# how to read this array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> int(9)
  ["obj"]=> int(3569)
  ["gen"]=> int(0)
  [1]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> int(0)
  }
}
```

I am learning PHP and came upon this while using `var_dump`.

I understand that in this array there is 4 keys, 0 obj gen and 1, and in these keys the values are as such, the number 9, the integer 3569, the integer 0 but what does the last part mean??

```
[1]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) }
```

If someone can help or link me to some learning material that would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key `1` contains a nested array with a key `0` that has value `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The last part indicates that the value stored in `$array[1]` is another array.  This is unlike some languages that only allow one type of variable in an array.  It's entirely possible to nest arrays to the nth degree, as such:

```
$arrayInsanity = array(
    array (
        array(
            //etc..
        )
     )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a `<pre>` tag around your `var_dump()`. It'll make it clearer.

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($myArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a second array in the array with the key 1 where the 0th element value is int(0)

Answer (score 0):

It is another array inside your original array. That second array contains an integer with value 0. The whole array is termed multidimensional because it includes an array itself.

Next time, try `print_r()` on an array and look at the source code of the resulting output - it will be nicely laid out for you.